# How can I configure undertow to share sessions between a Servlet handler and a HttpServerExchange based handler?

Tags: session, servlets, undertow

I want to modify a web app using embedded undertow from using Servlets to using a HttpServerExchange-based framework. I'd like it to continue working while I change code a bit at a time. The crux seems to be making them share sessions. The two session types  seem to be pretty much the same under the hood.